# Remove Chrome Bookmarks with Powershell

Tags: google-chrome, powershell

I am looking for a way in powershell to remove and add bookmarks to chrome. Chrome Bookmarks are stored in a JSON file formatted like below, with the actual bookmarks being stored in the $data.roots.bookmark_bar.children object. I have tried  something like this:

```
$data = Get-content $chromebookmarkfile | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json    
$data | Where-Object {$data.Roots.Bookmark_bar.children.Name -Notmatch "^NA"} | Convertto-JSON | Out-File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\bookmarkupdated.js"
```

and it seems to remove all the bookmarks.

```
> {    "checksum": "f8d56bf82388c64d566247e1f510d0c8",    "roots": {
>       "bookmark_bar": {
>          "children": [ {
>             "date_added": "13186673111751399",
>             "id": "5",
>             "meta_info": {
>                "last_visited_desktop": "13189831127309905"
>             },
>             "name": "Facebook",
>             "type": "url",
>             "url": "https://www.facebook.com/"
>          }],
>          "date_added": "13186673028532299",
>          "date_modified": "13189832329106862",
>          "id": "1",
>          "name": "Bookmarks bar",
>          "type": "folder"
>       },
>       "other": {
>          "children": [  ],
>          "date_added": "13186673028532314",
>          "date_modified": "0",
>          "id": "2",
>          "name": "Other bookmarks",
>          "type": "folder"
>       },
>       "synced": {
>          "children": [  ],
>          "date_added": "13186673028532317",
>          "date_modified": "0",
>          "id": "3",
>          "name": "Mobile bookmarks",
>          "type": "folder"
>       }    },    "version": 1 }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$json = Get-Content $chromebookmarkfile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.Roots.Bookmark_bar.children = @($json.Roots.Bookmark_bar.children | where { $_.name -notmatch "^NA" })
$json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\bookmarkupdated.js" -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: This works like a dream creating the file. However, I run into a similar problem when I brute force creating the text of the file....when I replace the current Bookmarks file with the new one created by the script, Chrome does not load with any bookmarks. However, if I open the original Chrome-created bookmark file and overwrite all the text from the one created by the script it works and removes the correct bookmarks. This one has me scratching my head.

Its almost like the Chrome application fingerprints the file somehow.

Comment: I fixed it. Looks like Chrome encodes the file in UTF-8 and powershell's default is something different. This fixed the issue: 
$json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File "d:\tmp\bookmarkupdated.js" -Encoding UTF8

Comment: @Thomas Great find. I've included that in the answer.